# How do I compare the size of the value at a certain index in an array

Tags: python

Let's say I have 3 arrays of type int.

```
int[] arr1 = {1,3,8};
int[] arr1 = {2,5,3};
int[] arr1 = {3,7,7};
```

And I would like to compare each index to the other arrays at the same index and print which one is bigger in a descending order.

So the output would be 1 > 2

I couldn't get any further than this.. I was trying to do it with 2 arrays first and then try to scale it, making it dynamic, but I kept running into errors

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrays.Count; i++)
{
    for (int d = 0; d < _size; d++)
    {
        //array0: index: 0 value: 1
        //array0: index: 1 value: 3
        //array0: index: 2 value: 5
        var value = arrays[i][d];
        var value2 = arrays[i+1][d];

        Console.WriteLine($"array{i}: index:{d} value: {value}");
    }
}
```

based on any amount of arrays that there are?

Comment: This question was originally tagged with `c#`, not `python`. Almost all answers below assuming c#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to show you there are many ways to do it, here is one with tuples:

```cs
int[] arr1 = {1,3,8};
int[] arr2 = {2,5,3};
int[] arr3 = {3,7,7};
int[][] arrays = {arr1,arr2,arr3};
int arraySize = arr1.Length;
int nArrays = arrays.Length;
for (int d = 0; d < arraySize; d++)
{
    var list = new List<(int index,int value)>() {};
    for (int i = 0; i < nArrays; i++)
    {
        list.Add((index:i, value:arrays[i][d]));
    }
    list.Sort((i1,i2)=>i2.value.CompareTo(i1.value));
    Console.Out.Write($"Index {d}: ");
    for (int x = 0; x<nArrays-1; x++)
    {
        Console.Out.Write($"{list[x].value} from array {list[x].index} is greater than ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{list[nArrays-1].value} from array {list[nArrays-1].index}");
}
```

It produces a List of tuples of index and value, then sorts by value and uses the result to output the desired text. It ought to scale to more arrays and values. I tried to find a more elegant way to produce the list, but I haven't found one yet.

It produces this output:

```
Index 0: 3 from array 2 is greater than 2 from array 1 which is greater than 1 from array 0
Index 1: 7 from array 2 is greater than 5 from array 1 which is greater than 3 from array 0
Index 2: 8 from array 0 is greater than 7 from array 2 which is greater than 3 from array 1
```

I was also confused about the > sign in the output.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about the `>` sign's function in your output example, but the following code works for any number of `int[_size]` arrays in `arrays` var:

```csharp
if (arrays.Any())
{
    for (int d = 0; d < _size; d++)
    {
        var valuesAndIndexes = arrays
            .Select((arr, idx) => new { arrIndex = idx, arrValue = arr[d] })
            .OrderByDescending(i => i.arrValue)
            .Select(i => $"{i.arrValue} from array {i.arrIndex}");

        var output = $"Index {d}: {valuesAndIndexes.First()}";
        if (arrays.Count > 1)
        {
            output = String.Concat(output, $" is greater than {String.Join(" which is greater than ", valuesAndIndexes.Skip(1))}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(output);
    }
}
```

Assuming arrays you provided as an example the code's output will be:

```
Index 0: 3 from array 2 is greater than 2 from array 1 which is greater than 1 from array 0
Index 1: 7 from array 2 is greater than 5 from array 1 which is greater than 3 from array 0
Index 2: 8 from array 0 is greater than 7 from array 2 which is greater than 3 from array 1
```

**EDIT:**
The original question was tagged with c#, not python. My answer assumes c#, please do not blame me with -1 :)

Answer (score 1):

This approach might help you:

```
int[] arr1 = {1, 3, 8, 8};
int[] arr2 = {2, 5, 3, 3};
int[] arr3 = {3, 7, 7, 7};
var arrayByName = new Dictionary<string, int[]>
{
    {nameof(arr1), arr1},
    {nameof(arr2), arr2},
    {nameof(arr3), arr3}
};
for (var i = 0; i < arrayByName.FirstOrDefault().Value.Count(); i++)
{
    Console.Write($"Index{i}: ");
    var dataAtIndexByArrayName = arrayByName.Select(item => new
        {
            key = item.Key,
            value = item.Value[i]
        })
        .OrderByDescending(d => d.value)
        .ToDictionary(key => key.key, value => value.value);
    foreach (var data in dataAtIndexByArrayName)
        Console.Write(data.Key == dataAtIndexByArrayName.LastOrDefault().Key
            ? $"{data.Value} from array {data.Key}"
            : $"{data.Value} from array {data.Key} is greater than ");
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

and result is:

```
Index0: 3 from array arr3 is greater than 2 from array arr2 is greater than 1 from array arr1
Index1: 7 from array arr3 is greater than 5 from array arr2 is greater than 3 from array arr1
Index2: 8 from array arr1 is greater than 7 from array arr3 is greater than 3 from array arr2
Index3: 8 from array arr1 is greater than 7 from array arr3 is greater than 3 from array arr2
```

also you can customize **finalString**

Comment: +1 for using suggesting 'nameof()' and -1 for using string concatenation with `+=` in cycle which is a very bad practice. It performs badly because continous memory allocation (bigger and bigger sized memory blocks required in each cycle for storing the new string instance) and causes memory fragmentation which may result in OOM despite a lots of free memory available in process.